# Convergence of the series $\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,1],\mathbb R)$. Let us investigate the convergence of the series
>   $$
> \sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|,
> $$
>   where $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb R)$. Do there exist conditions on $f$ which ensure the convergence of the series? If yes, what are these conditions?

This series reminds the series of [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) which states that $\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|^2=\|f\|^2$. So the series $\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|^2$ converges for each $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb R)$ without any additional assumptions. However, the term of the series is squared in Parseval's identity and it seems that additional assumptions are required for the series without $2$ in the exponent to converge.

Using the triangle and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities, we can obtain the following inequality
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1|f(x)|\mathrm dx
&=\int_0^1\biggl|\sum_n\langle f,e_n\rangle e_n(x)\biggr|\mathrm dx\\
&\le\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|\int_0^1|e_n(x)|\mathrm dx\\
&\le\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|.
\end{align*}
Hence, if the function $f$ is not integrable, the series diverges.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\langle f,f\rangle <\infty$ is obviously not enough: The sequence $x = (1, \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots)$ is obviously in $\ell^2$, thus it corresponds to a function in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ which we will denote by $f$. We have $\langle f,f \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} <\infty$ due to parseval equality, but the harmonic series diverge.

However, if we have a $2\pi$-peridioc function $f$ with the condition $f' \in L^2$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle f, e_n \rangle | <\infty$.

To see this, first show that the fourier coefficients of $f,f'$ are connected with $$ \hat{f'}(n) = in\hat{f}(n)$$
Then we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty | \hat{f}(n) | =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|\hat{f'}(n)|}{n} $$ which we bound using Holder's inequality.

Comment: I have a few questions: (1) How do we know that there exists $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ and an ONB such that $\langle f,e_n\rangle=1/n$? (2) So you show that if $f'\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, then $\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|<\infty$. Does this imply the same result for $L^2[0,1]$? (3) Do you use any ONB or $\{e_n=e^{ixn}:n\in\mathbb Z\}$? (4) How can we show that $\langle f',e_n\rangle=n\langle f,e_n\rangle$? I think this is a nice answer but lack of details makes it difficult to understand and I hope that it is possible to show that the series converges under weaker assumptions.

Comment: There exists an isometry between any seperable hilbert spaces and $\ell^2$, this establishes the answer to your first 2 questions (ofcourse $f'$ has to be in the relevant $L^2$ space).
As for your 3rd question, i used ${e^{inx}}_{n=1}^\infty$ or "the same" basis, represented with sines and cosines.
Regarding your 4th question, another condition was needed (which i added).